# Как получить конкретный url на видео в youtube для VideoView

Tags: java, android, youtube, videoview, rtsp

Мне нужна ссылка (на mp4 файл, к примеру) для загрузки в VideoView через setVideoURL(). Я читал, что это можно реализовать через RTSP, но не особо представляю как(особенно, учитывая, что с выходом youtube api v3, многие способы устарели). Пробовал библиотеку [android-youtubeExtractor](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor), но не добился нужного результата.

Плюс ко всему, нужна поддержка android вплоть до версии 2.3(9)

Скажу сразу, стандартный проигрыватель из youtube api и iframe версия через WebView не подойдут...